# Adverbien und Adjektive

Tags: adjective, adverb

Gibt es neben „lang“ vs. „lange“ noch andere häufige Adverbien, die im Gebrauch mit Adjektiven verwechselt werden?

Insbesondere: Ist die Phrase "punktweiser Grenzwert" korrekt?

Comment: Ich habe eigentlich nicht gerne Anführungszeichen, die in die falsche Richtung zeigen.

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage leider nicht. Was meinst du mit *auf "weise" enden"? Vor allem, da "lang" oder "lange" ja nicht auf "weise" enden.

Comment: Ursprünglich wollte ich das auch nicht ändern, aber ich musste noch irgendwas machen, damit der Edit funktioniert (man muss sechs Zeichen ändern, und ich hatte nur zwei).

Comment: @splattne : Mir geht es um Adverbien, die im Gebrauch mit Adjektiven vermischt werden, so wie in der Frage "wie lang" und "wie lange" oder auch "punktweiser Grenzwert".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*punktweise* ist ein Adverb, das zum Beispiel auf folgende Weise verwendet werden kann:

> (fn) heißt **punktweise konvergent** gegen eine Funktion ...

Der Begriff "punktweiser Grenzwert", bei dem das Wort als Adjektiv verwendet wird, scheint sich mittlerweile eingebürgert zu haben. Das ist auch die Schlussfolgerung, zu der [diese Diskussion auf Wikipedia zum Thema](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_Diskussion%3aMathematik/Archiv5#.E2.80.9EPunktweise_Konvergenz.E2.80.9C) kommt.

---

Andere Beispiele fallen mir nicht ein. Ich weiß nicht, ob das Adverb "bald" dazu gezählt werden kann, weil *baldig* ja ein anderes Wort (Adjektiv) ist.

> Ich komme bald.
>   Mein baldiges Kommen

Answer (score 1):

Der "punktweise Grenzwert" klingt zwar nicht schön, aber in Ermangelung einer guten Alternative ist der Ausdruck wohl akzeptabel. Schließlich ist das Adjektiv "pünktlich" schon anderweitig belegt. Sprachlich korrekter wäre vielleicht der "punktweise genommene Grenzwert".

Was man im Verkehrsfunk manchmal hört ist die "teilweise Sperrung" der Autobahn. Auch "stückweise Annäherung", "stufenweise Abschaltung" (der Atomkraftwerke) und "stundenweise Betreuung" habe ich schon gehört, aber als *korrekt* würde ich dies alles (noch?) nicht empfinden.

Answer (score 0):

Ja, es gibt eine Menge Adverbien. Siehe auch [Kategorie:Adverb (Deutsch)](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kategorie%3aAdverb_%28Deutsch%29) auf Wiktionary.

Comment: Hm, irgendwie ist das nicht das, was ich im Sinn hatte, ich muß wohl nochmal über die richtige Formulierung der Frage nachdenken. Trotzdem danke.

Comment: Ich habe die Frage jetzt verändert und präzisiert (nur damit niemand glaubt, dass das eine unpassende Antwort zum Zeitpunkt des Posts war).